# Changing the length of a parameter in all Stored Procedures with a certain parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to alter the length of a certain parameter in all stored procs that take that parameter.

This gets me the proc names but is there a way to embed this within an ALTER for all of them?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.SPECIFIC_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS p
WHERE p.PARAMETER_NAME = '@[PARAMETER_NAME]'
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could change param length directly. Just one idea.

You can get the text of your stored procedures looking at INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '@YourParam' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

and for each ROUTINE_DEFINITION change CREATE by ALTER, change param length and execute it, just to save new settings.